# clang tools for replace names for large project

Tags: clang, clang-static-analyzer

I am working on some project which has large number of files, and I want to change some names automatically, for example I have a class named as "Test_http", I want to replace it with some other name in the whole project.
I've tried with clang-tidy, it can detect the class name, but I cannot replace all the occurrences in the project, it can only replace it at the current location.
Is there any way to finish this task: detect one variable name, and replace all the occurrences in the project with another name automatically? thanks

Comment: You can try to use [csope](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/), it's easy to use and it has an option to find and replace a particular string.

Comment: thanks, @deLta, I didn't describe my problem clearly, actually I don't know which name I need to replace, the rule will detect, and there will be a large mount of names need to be replaced, so it's not possible to finish manually